# How to skip nil values when calculating the average of the levels of a tree in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have implemented the following function using Swift. It calculates the averages at each level of a tree. It works fine as long as I don't include nils for values of nodes.

***Failing***

Basically, it is failing for this test case: `[10,5,15,null,null,6,20]`

To visualize it the tree will still look like this:

```
       10

   5         15

          6     20
```

basically skipping the nils. 
My output is this: `[10.0,10.0]` when it should be `[10.0,10.0,13.0]`

***Passing***

It passes this test case: `[3,9,20,15,7]`
with correct output `[3.0,14.5,11.0]`

Visualized as

```
       3

   9        20

         15     7
```

**Implementation**

```
func averageOfLevels(_ root: TreeNode?) -> [Double] {
        var avg = [Double]()
        var queue = [TreeNode?]()//an array that will be treated as a queue

        queue.append(root)

        while(!queue.isEmpty) { //while there is at least one discovered node
            let current: TreeNode! = queue.first!

            var levelSum = 0.0
            var count = Double(queue.count) //get total number of nodes at this new level
            for node in queue {
                if let myNode = node {
                    levelSum = levelSum + Double(myNode.val)
                    queue.removeFirst() //pop already visited value from the queue
                }
            }

            var levelAvg = Double(levelSum / count)
            avg.append(levelAvg)

            //step to new level
            if (current.left != nil) {queue.append(current!.left)} //append left node to queue
            if (current.right != nil) {queue.append(current!.right)} //append right node to queue
            //now repeat for new level
        }
        return avg
    }
```

Comment: use flatMap on my queue? how would I do that when the elements are of type TreeNode?

Comment: That would work if you appended each value to an array of optional Integers in the `for` loop. Then you could return the value of `flatMap` at the end.

Comment: still failing the same test case: for node in queue {
                if let myNode = node {
                    if myNode.val != nil {
                        levelSum = levelSum + Double(myNode.val)
                    }
                    queue.removeFirst() //pop already visited value from the queue
                }
            }

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
for node in queue {
    if let myNode = node {
        if let newNum = Double(myNode.val) {
            levelSum += newNum 
        }
        queue.removeFirst() //pop already visited value from the queue
    }
 }
```

Comment: Or `levelSum += Double(node?.val ?? 0)`

Comment: I really need to use optional chaining more often it's much more elegant

Comment: still failing the same test case: for node in queue {
                if let myNode = node {
                    if myNode.val != nil {
                        levelSum = levelSum + Double(myNode.val)
                    }
                    queue.removeFirst() //pop already visited value from the queue
                }
            }

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be simpler to do a depth-first search instead of a breadth-first search.  Then you can use the call stack instead of maintaining your own queue:

```
extension TreeNode {

    func levelMeans() -> [Double] {
        var sumAtLevel = [Double]()
        var countAtLevel = [Double]()

        func visit(_ node: TreeNode, level: Int) {
            if sumAtLevel.count == level {
                sumAtLevel.append(0)
                countAtLevel.append(0)
            }

            sumAtLevel[level] += node.val
            countAtLevel[level] += 1

            if let left = node.left { visit(left, level: level + 1) }
            if let right = node.right { visit(right, level: level + 1) }
        }

        visit(self, level: 0)
        return zip(sumAtLevel, countAtLevel).map({ $0.0 / $0.1 })
    }

}

let test0 =
    TreeNode(10,
             TreeNode(5),
             TreeNode(15,
                      TreeNode(6),
                      TreeNode(20)))
print(test0.levelMeans())

# Output: [10.0, 10.0, 13.0]
```